# Question about semi-continuous functional

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, semicontinuous-functions

My research is dealing with a functional $f(x,y): \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}^+$, that I know is lower-semicontinuous in both $x$ and $y$. I would like the following to be true, but am having trouble proving it:

> **Conjecture:** If $f(x_0,y_0) > M$, then there is some open neighborhood of $(x_0,y_0)$, call it $U$, such that $f(x,y) > M$ for all $(x,y) \in U$.

Is this true? Any help would be much appreciated.

**edit:** The particular functional is related to geodesic flow. See my comment below for more details.

Comment: When you say "lsc in both $x$ and $y$", I assume you mean separately, i.e. "lsc in $x$ for fixed $y$" and "lsc in $y$ for fixed $x$", for if you mean "lsc on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^k$" it's trivial. In general, that doesn't follow. Just like separate continuity doesn't imply continuity, separate semicontinuity doesn't imply semicontinuity. You need something extra. Have you perhaps anything extra?

Comment: $x$ is in a coordinate chart on a manifold, and $y$ is a tangent vector at $x$. $f$ is the smallest time it takes the geodesic to flow back to $x$. If it never returns to $x$ we say that $f(x,y) = ∞$. I want to say that if $f(x_0, y_0) > M$ then points near $(x_0,y_0)$ also take at least $M$ time to return, or at least the the return time is comparable to $M$.

Comment: Uh, differential geometry. Not my strong point. I would expect that the return time is lower semicontinuous (together), but that's just an uneducated guess.

Comment: Forgive me if this is trivial, but wouldn't lower-sc on $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^k$ imply lower-sc in each subspace separately? After rereading my resources, I think I'm given lower-sc in the cotangent bundle as a whole, which should help.

Comment: Yes, lower semicontinuity on $X \times Y$ implies that the function is separately lower semicontinuous. The other direction fails. Re-read once again to be sure, if you're indeed given lower semicontinuity on the tangent bundle (ought to be tangent, not cotangent, methinks) you're done, that's precisely what you ask for in the question.